# I have two tables,first table T1 contains id and name and the name contains 5 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,first table T1 contains id and name and the name contains 5 values.And the second table T2 contains id and amonut_paid and the amount paid column contains 3 values.I want to display the all names from the table T1 and the amount_paid in sql

Comment: All names?? But only 3 names have amount_paid, what you will show for rest 2??

Answer (score 1):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` and then use `IFNULL` for replacing the `NULL` with `0`

```
SELECT T1.name,IFNULL(T2.amount_paid,0)
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2  ON T1.id=T2.id
```

Note: Instead of `IFNULL` you can also use `COALESCE` as [strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) suggested.

Comment: Note that COALESCE is ANSI compliant

Answer (score 0):

Use an `LEFT JOIN` on both these tables T1 and T2, so that it shows only the rows where a NAME against AMOUNT_PAID exists (`INNER JOIN` provides the rows available in both these tables)

```
SELECT T1.name, T2.amount_paid
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id

--RETURNS 3 rows as per your example
```

Use an `OUTER JOIN` on both these tables T1 and T2, so that it shows all the rows irrespective of the values being present in these tables.

```
RETURNS 5 rows as per your example
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` here, Because your `t1 table` contains 5 names and you want to display all name from t1 table. And your `t2 table` contains only three entry(amount_paid).

```
Select t1.name, t2.amount_paid
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```